# C# Перегрузка операций преобразования типов

Tags: c#, массивы, указатели, преобразование-типов

Можно ли в классе определить перегрузку преобразования типов другого типа?

Пример:

В классе определено свойство `public float[][] Matrix {get; set;}`

Мне нужно получать доступ к каждому элементу массива без индексации.
Для этого я могу определить свойство `public float* M1 {get; set;}` которое хранит адрес первой ячейки.

Можно ли перегрузить оператор преобразования типа для `float*`?

Что бы я мог делать так. `this.M1 = 4f` а внутри он изменяет значение по адресу и с получением значения также.

Или как еще можно реализовать подобное без явных указаний индексов элементов и дублирования кода?

Comment: Это невозможно, и наружу вообще не надо показывать unsafe код.

Comment: `this.M1 = 4f` - это всегда присваивает значение первой ячейке? Можно сделать свойство (управляемое, без указателей), которое делает именно это.

Comment: @ヒミコ это возможно, и ещё как

Comment: @return, ну перегрузите оператор = для указателя :)

Comment: @ヒミコ я про свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

В случае с матрицей используйте "*управляемые* указатели", т. е. *ссылки*:

```
public double[,] Matrix { get; }
public ref double M1 => ref Matrix[0, 0];
```

---

В случае с матрицей вы только зря тратите память, используйте свой `struct`/`class`:

```
public struct /*or `class`*/ Matrix
{
    public static readonly Matrix Identity = <...>;

    public double M1 { get; set; }
    <...>
}
```

---

`float[][]` является не матрицей, а вложенным (jagged) массивом, т. е. массивом массивов. Т. к. матрицы бывают только NxM, а вложенные массивы могут выглядеть вот так:

```
[1 57 44 -18 11]
[5]
[]
null
[40 2]
```

…то использовать вложенные массивы не целесообразно.

Comment: В какой версии языка можно объявлять свойства с оператором `ref`? Подчеркивает красным. У меня VS2015, Framework 4.

Comment: @CoollerFloyd у меня новейший C# .NET Core

Comment: @CoollerFloyd, а что это Вы, дяденька, застряли в legacy? :) Мир уже превью .NET палкой тыкает, а Вы на допотопном Framework допотопной версии сидите :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я тоже не хотел переходить на .NET Core (когда в `.csproj` поставил `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`, то весь код залился ворнингами…), но потом решился и не пожалел) чего стоят только 1 `Span` и те же `ref`

Comment: @return, nullable feature появилась гораздо позже .NET Core, более того: ее использование необязательно, так что можете использовать последнюю версию Core без таковой, хотя, как по мне, она крайне и крайне полезна. Да и пофиксить предупреждения несложно в старых проектах :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, я бы с радостью перешел, студия частично ставится на системный диск, а он у меня забит.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov я просто испугался, когда это увидел и подумал: "Ну, нахер!" Там у меня было 100+- файлов и править каждый… Ну, нахер! :) так же об nullable узнал, когда лазил по синтаксису `.csproj`, поэтому это был мой первый "опыт" знакомства с .NET Core

Comment: @CoollerFloyd так ответ мой удовлетворяет вашим требованиям или нет? просто .NET Core стал своеобразным стандартом для C# (если не указана платформа, знайте, это .NET Core)

Comment: @return, к сожалению в моем случае это решение не работает.

Comment: @CoollerFloyd вынужден капитулировать: для .NET Framework такого решения не существует… только если: `public double M1 { get => Matrix[0, 0]; set => Matrix[0, 0] = value; }`

Comment: @return, да, я уже сам подумал об этом ): . Спасибо.

Comment: @CoollerFloyd, ну, не сидеть же из-за этого на legacy-платформе. Снесите студию, если у Вас мало места, удалите старые SDK, оставив только runtime'ы, поставьте SDK новые и сидите пишите в каком-нибудь легковесном редакторе